# Disable parts of HTML code from a script

Tags: javascript, html

I need to disable some HTML code from a script that is parsed into a div box with a specified ID. I have no access to the source of the script. Just for example let's assume the script parses some headings `<h1>` with some text and some lists `<ul>` with some items `<li>`.
Some months ago I found a way to disable some parts of the code matching a specific pattern, but I can't remember how this works or how this was called. How can I disable every `<h1>` tag parsed into the div box?
EDIT: What I need is to find every tag with the pattern `<h1>` and let the browser ignore it.

Comment: Can you share what your HTML looks like?

Comment: Arbitrary HTML elements have no concept of being "disabled".

Comment: What do you mean by disable? Do you mean hide them? Use CSS and set them to `display: none`.

Comment: "I have no access to the source of the script" You mean you can't access the HTML source? If you can't access any script, there's nothing you can do, except via dev tools or a browser plug-in/add-on.

Comment: Can you be more specific ? If what you're asking is to allow the script to selectively parse your html elements without having access to the script, then I don't think its possible.

Comment: I read this as no access to the origional script used to 'disable' the HTML?

Comment: The HTML code that is parsed into the div box is from an external website. A provided script resolves some passed parameters to know what information to parse into the box. That is what I mean with no access to the source.

Answer (score 1):

`h1` can only be made invisible or hidden.

This can be easily accomplished using jQuery like:
`.hide()`, or `.css('display', 'none')`

The above will remove the element from the layout thus the space occupied by this element collapses.

```
.css('visibility', 'hidden')
```

The above will make the element transparent but the space is still occupied.

For some other elements such as `button` or `input`, they can be made disabled, such as:

```
<button type="button" disabled>Click Me!</button>
```

or

jQuery 1.6+:
`.prop('disabled', true);`

jQuery 1.5 or below:
`.attr('disabled', 'disabled');`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by disabled but you can hide them easily with JQuery?

```
$('#thediv h1').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just find all of the children of a certain item by tag name, and then remove them from the DOM.  They will still exist, but they won't be attached to the DOM anymore.

The HTML:

```
<div id="box">
    <h1>Inside the box</h1>
</div>
<h1>Outside the box</h1>
```

The JavaScript:

```
var box = document.getElementById('box');
var headers = box.getElementsByTagName('h1');

for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    box.removeChild(headers[i]);   
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6Lu6m4d/) example.

Comment: But that will render the elements inaccessible to any script whatsoever.

Comment: To *other* scripts, yes.  But your script will still be able to reference the `h1`s with the `headers` var.  You could easily place them back in if you wanted to.  It's not uncommon to detach a node from the DOM, perform a series of manipulations on it,and then re-attach it to the DOM.